# Storing "n" number of 2D matrices into a single 3D matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have "n" number of 2D matrices of same size. I want to store all these 2D matrices one by one into a single 3D numpy matrix/array.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this in python?

Comment: Have you tried to look by yourself before posting here? There's plenty of ways to do it, this question clearly doesn't show enough research effort.

Comment: @RandomGuy yes sir, I looked alot but all the methods were storing the 2 to 3 matrices. But I need a method where I would be storing a single matrix one by one into the 3d numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.dstack()` such as:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[2,3,4],[2,3,4]])
c = np.array([[3,4,5],[3,4,5]])
new_3d = np.dstack((a,b,c))
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]]

[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]]]
```

Update for new question:

Also, you can add another 2d again and again like:

```
d = np.array([[3,4,5],[3,4,5]])
new_3d = np.dstack((new_3d,d))
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2 3 3]
 [2 3 4 4]
 [3 4 5 5]]

 [[1 2 3 3]
 [2 3 4 4]
 [3 4 5 5]]]
```

Comment: But what if if there are 100 number of 2D matrices ??

Comment: @SaptarsheeSarkar I updated my answer, you can check.

Comment: Got it, while using dstack , when I am iterating through the final 3d array and want to get the a,b,c, & d matrices I ain't getting them in their original form ?

Comment: @SaptarsheeSarkar will be added with their original form, but I don't exactly understand your question.  Do you want to get them after the addition of the 3d matrix?